# Is my nginx rewrite correct?

Tags: nginx

I am using this config:

```
/test/([^'.]+)$ /test/index.php?id=$1
```

for my website. And for the redirection for non trailing slash am writing:

```
if(substr($_GET['id'], -1) != '/'){ //if no trailing slash then redirect! header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url').'/test/'.$_GET['id'].'/'); exit();
```

I just wanted to know that am i doing it right?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve, but seems a bit complicated solution to use both Nginx configuration and PHP.

Comment: Since you haven't presented your requirements, we cannot answer if your configuration fulfills the requirements or not...